# How to redirect Facebook request to my URL in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, redirect

I am requesting my friend, using simple code as below which is working very fine.

```
- (NSDictionary*)parseURLParams:(NSString *)query {
NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
    NSArray *kv = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *val =
    [kv[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    params[kv[0]] = val;
}
return params;
}


- (void)sendRequest {
// Display the requests dialog
[FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social."
 title:nil
 parameters:nil
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
         NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             // User clicked the "x" icon
             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
         } else {
             // Handle the send request callback
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 // User clicked the Send button
                 NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                 NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
             }
         }
     }
}];
}
```

as the received user click the request, it redirect it too appStore link of my App, whose Facebook ID I have used in **.plist** file.

I want to show URL which is mind, say www.myiosdeveloper.com, so How can I redirect it.

I found something in documentation, but I am unable to understand it.

[Request Dialog Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Below in the page of above given documentation, it says,

```
     https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?
     app_id=APP_ID&
     =Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
     redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

So, what is it, please explain. 
Can SDK gives me permission to do as I want to, i.e redirect to my page.

Answer (score 0):

Assign that URL to the Canvas URL. Its simple.